# Will I lose Quiet when replaying a mission?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I currently have a completed run and Quiet still sticks around as a buddy. Now I would like to replay some of the older missions. So does replaying missions have any effect on the storyline or can cause the lose of a companion, specifically her (because keeping her was kind of tedious)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can replay older missions as much as you want with no danger of losing any of your buddies.

Comment: Pfffew. Thank god. Playing that damn mission another 7 times would be kinda stupid.